# Weak derivative in $L^2(0,T;V)$ for $V$ a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

I am working in *Navier-Stokes Equations* by *Roger Temam* and he uses some notions that are not very clear to me:

For $V$ a Hilbert space and $V'$ its dual, we are considering $u \in L^2(0,T;V)$, where
$$L^2(0,T;V) = \left\{u:[0,T] \to V~\bigg|~ \int_0^T \|u(t)\|^2_V~dt< + \infty\right\},$$
and the author says that "its derivative $u'$ belongs to $L^2(0,T;V')$". But what does he exactly mean by "its derivative" $?$ I am familiar with the concept of weak derivative of function in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but as here our functions are valued in $V$, I am not totally comfortable with this notion. Does that mean that there is some function $u'\in L^2(0,T;V')$ such that, for all $ \varphi\in  C^\infty_0([0,T])$ (compactly supported functions valued in $\mathbb R$)
$$\int_0^T u \partial_t\varphi~dt = - \int_0^Tu' \varphi~dt,$$
or that for all $ \varphi\in  C^\infty_0([0,T], V)$ (compactly supported functions valued in $V$)
$$\int_0^T (u,  \partial_t\varphi)_V~dt = - \int_0^T(u', \varphi)_V~dt ~?$$
Where $(\cdot, \cdot)_V$ the scalar product in $V$.

Comment: I struggled with these things a lot in the beginning of my PhD studies. Finally I found a book by John Hunter which was very helpful. This question is essentially the same as the present one and it contains a link to the book, also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1717522/8157